# How to add formatting when exporting to excel in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is when using a view file to generate an excel file. like:
in controller:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.xls"'
```

then in view:

```
<table><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr><table>
```

Is it possible to add formatting such as color to cells? like:

```
<td style="background-color=red">foo</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting -- I didn't know you could make Excel spreadsheets through HTML tables.  (I just tried it myself and was amazed.)  I don't think CSS will work very reliably -- you're probably stuck with HTML as it existed around  HTML 3.2 (circa 1996).  Although I cringe a little writing it, this worked for me:

```
<td bgcolor="red">foo</td>
```

or

```
<td bgcolor="#f00">foo</td>
```

I tested this in OpenOffice.org 3.2.

That being said, it might be worth learning the MS Office XML format if you need a lot of control over formatting.  If I remember correctly, you can apply the formatting yourself in Excel, then unzip the `.xlsx` file, and see what it wrote out.

Comment: thanks for answering! never occured to me to use bgcolor! will try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Not a problem.  Use it with care.  :)